# Azure ML SDK to DataIKU (python Recepie) integration

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

WE are installing Azure Machine Learning SDK in Python Code Recipe in DataIKU.

The Model coding is more manual when using SDK, Is there a way where we can create models in ML Studio (Drag and Drop) and use it's service in Python to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a forthcoming feature of the Pipelines Designer UI, in which you can use custom Modules in the drag-and-drop fashion you propose. This UI will be built on top of Pipeline Modules which already exist today. Check out [this notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-how-to-use-modulestep.ipynb) for how to create a custom module that is easy to plug-and-play using the SDK.

Comment: Hi Anders,Thank for your response. We are setting up Azure ML SDK in Python. When we are creating models using Azure ML SDK in Python notebook We have to manually write the code to use feature of Azure ML and Scikit learn-- But if we model in ML studio we will do all that easily by drag and drop. Required solution is Can we build a model in Azure ML Studio and use the model in Azure ML SDK (Python Notebook). No more manual coding for Model creation will be involved. Please suggest.